# MySQL ERROR 1045 Access denied for 'nova'@'controller'

Tags: mysql, permissions, openstack-nova

## Description

I installed Openstack Wallaby using [OpenStack Installation Guide](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/), all command and configuration is on my [Github](https://github.com/hojat-gazestani/Wallaby).
This LAB is running on VirtualBox and I have another LAB with the same configuration and Openstack version on ESXi without any problem.

At this point **one controller** with **two compute** node.

### In the below section improve database permission confgured correctly

*Databases are created properly:*

```
user@controller001:~$ sudo mysql
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| glance             |
| information_schema |
| keystone           |
| mysql              |
| nova               |
| nova_api           |
| nova_cell0         |
| performance_schema |
| placement          |
+--------------------+
```

*Grant all permissions for those databases:*

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR nova;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for nova@%                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `nova`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*3A4A03AC22526F6B591010973A741D59A71D728E' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `nova`.* TO `nova`@`%`                                                      |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `nova_cell0`.* TO `nova`@`%`                                                |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `nova_api`.* TO `nova`@`%`                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

*Have access to databases remotely from compute node:*

```
user@compute001:~$ mysql -unova -popenstack -h controller001

MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| nova               |
| nova_api           |
| nova_cell0         |
+--------------------+
```

### Mysql log after restarting nova services:

```
user@controller001:~$ sudo systemctl restart nova-*

user@controller001:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log
2021-10-02 12:52:12 112 [Warning] Aborted connection 112 to db: 'nova' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 118 [Warning] Aborted connection 118 to db: 'nova_api' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 116 [Warning] Aborted connection 116 to db: 'nova' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 119 [Warning] Aborted connection 119 to db: 'nova_api' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 115 [Warning] Aborted connection 115 to db: 'nova' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 113 [Warning] Aborted connection 113 to db: 'nova' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 114 [Warning] Aborted connection 114 to db: 'nova' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 117 [Warning] Aborted connection 117 to db: 'nova' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 109 [Warning] Aborted connection 109 to db: 'nova' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 110 [Warning] Aborted connection 110 to db: 'nova' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 111 [Warning] Aborted connection 111 to db: 'nova' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 108 [Warning] Aborted connection 108 to db: 'nova_cell0' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 103 [Warning] Aborted connection 103 to db: 'nova_api' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 102 [Warning] Aborted connection 102 to db: 'nova_api' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:12 105 [Warning] Aborted connection 105 to db: 'nova_cell0' user: 'nova' host: 'controller001' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-02 12:52:16 141 [Warning] Access denied for user 'nova'@'controller001' (using password: YES)
2021-10-02 12:52:16 142 [Warning] Access denied for user 'nova'@'controller001' (using password: YES)
2021-10-02 12:52:17 147 [Warning] Access denied for user 'nova'@'controller001' (using password: YES)
```

### Got an error reading communication packets

[Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets) are some suggestions to resolve this error:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024 * 1024 * 256; 
set @@global.max_connections = 400;
SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=6000;
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
```

### Any try to discover new host make the below error:

```
user@controller001:~$ sudo su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 discover_hosts --verbose" nova
....
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'nova'@'controller001' (using password: YES)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

### And, but I am not sure it is a bug or not

```
user@controller001:~$ os hypervisor list
Unexpected API Error. Please report this at http://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/ and attach the Nova API log if possible.
<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError'> (HTTP 500) (Request-ID: req-d6edcfa3-ccf2-4eb8-80f8-041cb55e772d)
```

### name configuration:

```
user@controller001:~$ . admin-openrc 
user@controller001:~$ os endpoint list
+----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------+
| ID                               | Region    | Service Name | Service Type | Enabled | Interface | URL                            |
+----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------+
| 1e2f0fc829f84a53a337bbb70e7679af | RegionOne | nova         | compute      | True    | internal  | http://controller001:8774/v2.1 |
| 38e967a4c87f4464ba6ac965c889f6a4 | RegionOne | placement    | placement    | True    | admin     | http://controller001:8778      |
| 398d51ab439f4afc8fb7c71adc1bf3a9 | RegionOne | keystone     | identity     | True    | internal  | http://controller001:5000/v3/  |
| 4aaf9ac0ccec41978e541a0de0e55ed4 | RegionOne | nova         | compute      | True    | public    | http://controller001:8774/v2.1 |
| 52ba2047ed864b9aa6ad352ba2fe59dc | RegionOne | nova         | compute      | True    | admin     | http://controller001:8774/v2.1 |
| 659ed7ae84074b30a6a4941648b994c3 | RegionOne | placement    | placement    | True    | internal  | http://controller001:8778      |
| 9cd126c1f07e4b13946edcdc80f9f215 | RegionOne | placement    | placement    | True    | public    | http://controller001:8778      |
| aec5b18b834b4a9cad8a4efb83b1b1d7 | RegionOne | glance       | image        | True    | internal  | http://controller001:9292      |
| b1a13f51438c40b8b74ec25b89efebab | RegionOne | glance       | image        | True    | public    | http://controller001:9292      |
| c35c703090f3478aa7d960293fde1bf0 | RegionOne | keystone     | identity     | True    | admin     | http://controller001:5000/v3/  |
| ca231e48c3ad406c8ec757c765b651a6 | RegionOne | glance       | image        | True    | admin     | http://controller001:9292      |
| ff927678f6634475bd80bdba7effc3fc | RegionOne | keystone     | identity     | True    | public    | http://controller001:5000/v3/  |
+----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------+
user@controller001:~$ sudo su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 list_cells" nova
+-------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+
|  Name |                 UUID                 |                Transport URL                |                Database Connection                 | Disabled |
+-------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+
| cell0 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |                    none:/                   | mysql+pymysql://nova:****@controller001/nova_cell0 |  False   |
| cell1 | e62ffdc8-5f28-43ef-9bcb-404812faaeae | rabbit://openstack:****@controller001:5672/ |    mysql+pymysql://nova:****@controller001/nova    |  False   |
+-------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+
user@controller001:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 controller001

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

172.16.50.41    controller001
172.16.50.42    compute011
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, the issue seems to be a different one. If the configs differ from your github repo please add the current config settings to your post. What is the bind_address for mariadb?

Comment: @eblock this is my new address you can find exact configuration: https://github.com/hojat-gazestani/Wallaby

Comment: @eblock bind_address for mariadb is controller001 management interface, as you can see in file: /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/99-openstack.cnf : bind-address = 172.16.50.41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not related to MariaDB permissions or databases URL.

Problem solved using this [bug discription](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/+bug/1769635) and there is [another](https://pnyet.web.id/solved-openstack-nova-access-denied-user-nova-localhost) solution that doesn't work for me. Creating cells exactly like [nova installation guied](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/wallaby/install/controller-install-ubuntu.html) worked for me and adding **transport-url** and **database-connection** to *nova-mange* command was my fault although it was working for me in the past.

> "If you don't specify --database_connection then nova-manage will use
> the [database]/connection value from your config file, and mangle the
> database name to have a _cell0 suffix."
>
> And:
>
> "If your databases are on separate hosts then you should specify
> --database_connection or make certain that the nova.conf being used has the [database]/connection value pointing to the same
> user/password/host that will work for the cell0 database. If the cell0
> mapping was created incorrectly, it can be deleted using the
> nova-manage cell_v2 delete_cell command and then run map_cell0 again
> with the proper database connection value."
>
> So I think what probably happened is that when you ran map_cell0, it
> created a nova_api.cell_mappings record with the wrong database
> connection URL, because now db sync, which is relying on the
> cell_mappings table record to connect to the cell0 database, is
> failing because it's looking for nova_api_cell0 but you have
> nova_cell0.
>
> This is the exact code that is creating the default cell0 connection
> URL if you didn't specify --database-connection when running
> map_cell0:
>
> So I think you probably just want to (1) delete the cell0 mapping (2)
> run map_cell0 again and ensure it creates a cell0 entry with the
> correct database connection URL and then (3) run nova-manage db sync
> again.

```
sudo su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 map_cell0" nova
sudo su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 create_cell --name=cell1 --transport-url rabbit://openstack:****@controller001:5672/ --database_connection mysql+pymysql://nova:****@controller001/nova  --verbose" nova 


user@controller001:~$ sudo su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 list_cells" nova
+-------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------+
|  Name |                 UUID                 |               Transport URL               |               Database Connection                | Disabled |
+-------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------+
| cell0 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |                   none:/                  | mysql+pymysql://nova:****@controller001/nova_cell0 |  False   |
| cell1 | 553970ef-335a-4cf1-90fb-8268c49d5fad | rabbit://openstack:****@controller001:5672/ |    mysql+pymysql://nova:****@controller001/nova    |  False   |
+-------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------+

user@controller001:~$ sudo su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 delete_cell --cell_uuid  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" nova
user@controller001:~$ sudo su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 delete_cell --cell_uuid  553970ef-335a-4cf1-90fb-8268c49d5fad" nova



user@controller001:~$ sudo su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage api_db sync" nova
user@controller001:~$ sudo su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 map_cell0" nova
user@controller001:~$ sudo  su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 create_cell --name=cell1 --verbose" nova
--transport-url not provided in the command line, using the value [DEFAULT]/transport_url from the configuration file
--database_connection not provided in the command line, using the value [database]/connection from the configuration file
d448f914-53fa-410c-8f89-407e33c96c3f
user@controller001:~$ sudo su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage db sync" nova
user@controller001:~$ sudo su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 list_cells" nova
+-------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------+
|  Name |                 UUID                 |               Transport URL               |               Database Connection                | Disabled |
+-------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------+
| cell0 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |                   none:/                  | mysql+pymysql://nova:****@controller001/nova_cell0 |  False   |
| cell1 | d448f914-53fa-410c-8f89-407e33c96c3f | rabbit://openstack:****@controller001:5672/ |    mysql+pymysql://nova:****@controller001/nova    |  False   |
+-------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------+

user@controller001:~$ openstack compute service list --service nova-compute
+----+--------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
| ID | Binary       | Host      | Zone | Status  | State | Updated At                 |
+----+--------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
|  5 | nova-compute | compute21 | nova | enabled | up    | 2021-10-09T13:59:32.000000 |
+----+--------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
```